# Passing case class name as a function argument but takes entire path of case class

Tags: string, list, scala, class, circe

I have a case class

```
case class S3FileRecords(
                            rank: Integer,
                            name: String,
                        )
```

and while passing this case class name inside the function of my class, its taking the entire path of case class instead of just taking the case class name.

My class:

```
class LocalFileReader extends FileHandler {

 def read[S3FileRecords](rootDir: String, fileName: String): (List[String], List[S3FileRecords]) = {

    // generate full path using rootDir and fileName
    val file = new File(rootDir, fileName)


    //Read content from the file path
    val fileContent = new FileInputStream(file);

    // zip data
    val zipFileContent = new GZIPInputStream(fileContent)

    //convert to json
    val jsonfileContent = Source.fromInputStream(zipFileContent).mkString
 

     //Deserialize jsonFileContent
     val (err, ok) = jsonfileContent
         .split("\n")
         .map(decodeWithError)
         .partitionMap(identity)


    (err.toList, ok.toList)

}

def decodeWithError(str: String): Either[String, S3FileRecords] = 
{
    decode[S3FileRecords](str) match {
        case Right(value) => Right(value)
        case Left(ParsingFailure(message, _)) => Left(s"Error parsing string; Message: $message; Original string: $str")
        case Left(DecodingFailure(message, ops)) => {
            val failedCursor = str.asJson.hcursor.replay(ops).focus.toString
            Left(s"Error decoding to ${classOf[S3FileRecords].toString};" +
                s" Error Message: $message, Failed cursor: $failedCursor; Original record: $str")
        }
    }
}
}
```

(err.toList, ok.toList)
This is throwing below ERROR :

> Type mismatch. Required: scala.collection.immutable.List[S3FileRecords], found: scala.collection.immutable.List[user.path.s3FileEvent.S3FileRecords]

where S3FileRecords is the case class and user/path/s3FileEvent is the location of case class - S3FileRecords

Comment: Can you please share your `import` statements. Maybe you have a problem with having 2 classes with same name from different packages.

Comment: Here are the import statements: import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.syntax._

import java.io.{File, FileInputStream}
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream
import scala.io.Source
import com.cxi.handlers.FileHandler --> This is the trait that I inherited in my class